# Show endomorphism $\phi$ is determined by $\phi(e_1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

Say $\phi \in End_{M_n(D)}(D^n) $ I'm trying to show $\phi$ is determined by $\phi(e_1)$ and that $\phi(e_1)=de_1$ where $d \in D$

To show it's determined by $\phi(e_1)$ I have used the property that $\phi(M.e_1)=M \phi(e_1)$ and that $M.e_1 \in D^n$.  Is that sufficient? Also I'm not sure how to do the second part of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $D$ is a division ring as in one of your previous questions and that $\{e_i\}_{1≤i≤n}$ is the canonical basis.

For the first part you know that $\phi$ is determined on $e_1,\dots, e_n$. Then you can use [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) to show that $\phi$ is actually only determined on $e_1$.

---

For the second part, you know that you can write 
$$\phi(e_1) = d_1e_1+\cdots+d_n e_n \tag 1$$

Then, consider the following matrix (for the case $n=4$) :

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 &  1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

The idea is that $M_2 \cdot e_i$ is $e_i$ for $i≠2$, and is $e_1+e_2$ for $i=2$. Thanks to this matrix, we are able to show that $d_2 = 0$ in $(1)$ (and then you can do the same for $d_i, i>2$). Indeed :

> $$\phi(Me_1)=\phi(e_1) = d_1e_1+d_2e_2+\cdots+d_n e_n = M\phi(e_1) = d_1e_1+d_2(e_1+e_2)+\cdots+d_n e_n$$ which yields $d_2e_2=0$, i.e. $d_2=0$.